# How to use a prop function inside of useEffect with eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I want to call a prop function inside of `useEffect`. The following code works without any warnings:

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.handleClick(id);
}, [id]);
```

But eslint is complaining that `props` not being a dependency.

If I add it as a dependency, the code no longer works and I get a maximum re-render error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.handleClick(id);
}, [id, props]);
```

How can I fix this lint issue?

**Sample code:**

```
const ParentGrid = ({rows, columns}) => {
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState(null);

    const handleClick = selectedRows => {
        setSelection(selectedRows.map(i => rows[i]));
    };

    return (
        <ChildGrid
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            handleClick={handleClick} />
    );
}

const ChildGrid = props => {
    const {data, handleClick, ...rest} = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        handleClick(selectedRows);
    }, [selectedRows]);
  
    // ...etc
};
```

Comment: See here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880. I use this line `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: You doesn't need to place not important to change into useEffect dependency list.

Comment: What triggers that `id` to change in your component? It is possible that you don't have to use `useEffect` to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Hangindev thank you for the tip, I refactored it to avoid `useEffect`

Comment: @SAKURA You're welcome. Just to let you know the reason of the maximum re-render error is because `handleClick` triggers a state change in `ParentGrid` which causes a re-render and a new `handleClick` function is created and leads to the re-run of the `useEffect`'s callback inside `ChildGrid`arrow...♻ To avoid it, refactoring is a solution, or you can use `useCallback` to create a memoized `handleClick` function as @iamaatoh suggested. [useCallback docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Answer (score 10):

I see alot of weird and incorrect answers here so I felt the need to write this.

The reason you are reaching maximum call depth when you add the function to your dependency array is because it does not have a stable identity. In react, functions are recreated on every render if you do not wrap it in a `useCallback` hook. This will cause react to see your function as changed on every render, thus calling your useEffect function every time.

One solution is to wrap the function in `useCallback` where it is defined in the parent component and add it to the dependency array in the child component. Using your example this would be:

```
const ParentGrid = ({rows, columns}) => {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = useCallback((selectedRows) => {
    setSelection(selectedRows.map(i => rows[i]));
  }, [rows]); // setSelection not needed because react guarantees it's stable

  return (
    <ChildGrid
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      handleClick={handleClick}
    />
  );
}

const ChildGrid = props => {
  const {data, handleClick, ...rest} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    handleClick(selectedRows);
  }, [selectedRows, handleClick]);
};
```

(This assumes the `rows` props in parent component does not change on every render)

Comment: This is a correct approach only if you have access to the parent component to wrap the callback in the `useCallback` hook

Comment: @Ramtin What is the alternative if you do not?

Answer (score 1):

One correct way to do this is to add `props.handleClick` as a dependency and memoize handleClick on the parent (useCallback) so that the function reference does not change unnecessarily between re-renders.

It is generally NOT advisable to switch off the lint rule as it can help with subtle bugs (current and future)

in your case, if you exclude handleClick from deps array, and on the parent the function was dependent on parent prop or state, your useEffect will not fire when that prop or state on the parent changes, although it should, because the handleClick function has now changed.

Answer (score 0):

you should destructure `handleClick` outside of props

at the start of the component you probably have something like this:

`const myComponent = (props) =>`

change to

`const myComponent = ({ handleClick, id })` basically you can pull out any props you know as their actual name

then use below like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleClick(id);
  }, [id, handleClick]);
```

or probably you don't actually need the function as a dependency so this should work

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleClick(id);
  }, [id]);
```

Comment: so this still didn't work for me, I tried to pull out the function before useEffect: `const {data, handleClick, ...rest} = props`; If I didn't add it to the dependency array, lint complains "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleClick'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps". If I do, it's the maximum update depth exceeded error

Comment: @SAKURA why are you passing `handleClick` to `useEffect` it sounds like the sort of function that should be called `onClick`?

Comment: the naming is bad, but basically the function is passing some data to the parent component every time the user selects a row in a grid. I ended up refactoring my code to avoid useEffect, to avoid the lint error

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (**not sure if it's a good practice**):

```
const { current: handleClick } = useRef(props.handleClick)

useEffect(() => {
    handleClick(id)
}, [id, handleClick])
```

Answer (score -2):

Add `props.handleClick` as the dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.handleClick(id);
}, [id, props.handleClick]);
```

Comment: I tried this but still got the error: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render

Comment: did you point it to the function `props.handleClick` .. not `props`?

Comment: also, is `handleClick` an inline-function when you are passing it to this component as a `prop`?

Comment: This isn't correct use case of `useEffect`. In `useEffect ` dependency you need place only important to change values. React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: if `handleClick` is a memoized function with `useCallback` in the parent component, this `useEffect` wouldn't trigger because the `handleClick` reference wouldn't change - which IMHO is a better way of controlling when the `useEffect` runs. Wouldn't disabling the lint introduce more bugs since it **is** actually using the `handleClick` function?

Comment: In my experience, that linting rule is 99.99% correct and you should trust it...